# Convert object with array values into array of object

Tags: ruby

I do have this kind of params

```
params = { "people" => 
  {
    "fname" => ['john', 'megan'],
    "lname" => ['doe', 'fox']
  }
}
```

Wherein I loop through using this code

```
result = []
params["people"].each do |key, values|
  
  values.each_with_index do |value, i|
    result[i] = {}
    result[i][key.to_sym] = value
  end

end
```

The problem on my code is that it always gets the last key and value.

```
[
 { lname: 'doe' },
 { lname: 'fox' }
]
```

i want to convert it into

```
[
  {fname: 'john', lname: 'doe'},
  {fname: 'megan', lname: 'fox'}
]
```

so that i can loop through of them and save to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result[i] = {}
```

The problem is that you're doing this each loop iteration, which resets the value and deletes any existing keys you already put there. Instead, only set the value to `{}` if it doesn't already exist.

```
result[i] ||= {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question has been answered but I'd like to mention an alternative calculation that does not employ indices:

```
keys, values = params["people"].to_a.transpose
  #=> [["fname", "lname"], [["john", "megan"], ["doe", "fox"]]]
```

```
keys = keys.map(&:to_sym)
  #=> [:fname, :lname]
```

```
values.transpose.map { |val| keys.zip(val).to_h }
  #=> [{:fname=>"john", :lname=>"doe"},
  #    {:fname=>"megan", :lname=>"fox"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your inner loop, you're resetting the i-th element to an empty hash:

```rb
result[i] = {}
```

So you only end up with the data from the last key-value-pair, i.e. `lname`.

Instead you can use this to only set it to an empty hash if it doesn't already exist:

```rb
result[i] ||= {}
```

So the first loop through, it gets set to `{}`, but after that, it just gets set to itself.

Alternatively, you can also use

```rb
result[i] = {} if !result[i]
```

which may or may not be more performant. I don't know.